# Simple bootloader is outside RAM, when running it through qemu

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, bootloader, qemu

I'm trying to run a simple bootloader using qemu.

```
start:
    jmp start

    times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
    db 55h
    db 0AAh
```

and what I've done and what I've got:

```
 $ nasm -f bin -o boot.bin boot.s

 $ dd if=/dev/zero of=boot.img bs=1M count=64
64+0 records in
64+0 records out
67108864 bytes (67 MB) copied, 0.178296 s, 376 MB/s

 $ dd status=noxfer conv=notrunc if=boot.bin of=boot.img
1+0 records in
1+0 records out

 $ qemu -pflash boot.img 
qemu: fatal: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0x000a0000

EAX=00000000 EBX=00000000 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000633
ESI=00000000 EDI=00000000 EBP=00000000 ESP=00000000
EIP=000affd6 EFL=00000002 [-------] CPL=0 II=0 A20=1 SMM=0 HLT=0
ES =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
CS =f000 ffff0000 0000ffff 00009b00
SS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
DS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
FS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
GS =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00009300
LDT=0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008200
TR =0000 00000000 0000ffff 00008b00
GDT=     00000000 0000ffff
IDT=     00000000 0000ffff
CR0=60000010 CR2=00000000 CR3=00000000 CR4=00000000
DR0=00000000 DR1=00000000 DR2=00000000 DR3=00000000 
DR6=ffff0ff0 DR7=00000400
CCS=00000000 CCD=00000000 CCO=ADDB    
EFER=0000000000000000
FCW=037f FSW=0000 [ST=0] FTW=00 MXCSR=00001f80
FPR0=0000000000000000 0000 FPR1=0000000000000000 0000
FPR2=0000000000000000 0000 FPR3=0000000000000000 0000
FPR4=0000000000000000 0000 FPR5=0000000000000000 0000
FPR6=0000000000000000 0000 FPR7=0000000000000000 0000
XMM00=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM01=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM02=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM03=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM04=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM05=00000000000000000000000000000000
XMM06=00000000000000000000000000000000 XMM07=00000000000000000000000000000000
Aborted
```

All these things I'm doing in Debian x64.
I've tried to use linker scripts and elf64 configuration when building object file, but it doesn't work. I guess the problem is in the code of bootloader. But where?

Comment: Ok, I admit not playing with QEMU, or even bootloaders.  But as I recall, early boot is in 16-bit real, correct?  Which flavor of JMP did it assemble as?  (Flavors of JMP: http://read.seas.harvard.edu/cs261/hwref/i386/JMP.htm )

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your "boot" code - not much to go wrong with it. I suspect that you've put your code at the end of all those zeros, not at the beginning where we want it, but I'm not familiar enough with `dd` to be sure.

Comment: @Frank Kotler, it's at the beginning, I've checked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the build script. Just use floppy boot:

```
qemu -fda boot.img
```

For details: http://wiki.osdev.org/QEMU